# Prove by induction that $(z^n)^*=(z^*)^n$ for all positive integers of n

Tags: complex-numbers, induction

Prove by induction that $(z^n)^*=(z^*)^n$ for all positive integers of n.

My knowledge of proving things by induction is still growing, so I wasn't really too sure on how to tackle the question as was quite different o the ones I've seen before.

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: is $z*$ the conjugate?

Comment: yes it is the conjugate of z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For induction you need the show that, for the smallest value of $n$ allotted, that the equality holds.  So for $n=1$,

$$(z^1)^*=z^*=(z^*)^1$$.

Now, for the induction phase you make the assumption that for some positive integer $k$, $(z^k)^*=(z^*)^k$.  The final step is to compute $(z^{k+1})^*$ using the assumption provided...

$$(z^{k+1})^*=(z^k\cdot z)^*=(z^k)^*z^*=(z^*)^kz^*=\underbrace{z^*\cdot z^*\cdots z^*}_{k+1\text{ times}}\cdot z^*=(z^*)^{k+1}$$

where the second to last step is $z^*$ multiplied $k+1$ times.  We also used the fact (unproven) that for two complex numbers $z,w$,

$$(zw)^*=z^*w^*$$

Thus the proof is complete.

Comment: thanks that's a great help to me

Comment: please upvote if you feel you are happy with it.